# Creating a X64 Windows 10 IOt image

Tags: windows, intel-atom, iot, windows-iot-core

I am Creating a X64 Windows 10 IOt image.
I am following this guide
https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/blob/master/Tools/README.md
I am at stage 4 “Import the required BSP (for example RPi2) using Import-IoTBSP”
I am using an Intel Atom x5-Z8350 CPU so I went over to this site
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/bsphardware
Selected Under Intel BSPS the link regarding the Atom x5-Z8350 namely:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/products/braswell/software-and-drivers.html
Downloaded and install the Board Support Package for Intel Atom® Processor Windows* 10 IoT Core 32-bit and 64-bit Platforms.
Its created several files in the following folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel IoT\Source-x64

[image]

My question is this when I run the Import-IoTBSP command I get the following error:
IoTCorePShell amd64 10.0.0.0 Test

The Command I run: `Import-IoTBSP APLx64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel IoT\Source-x64\BSP"`

The error I get :`Error: No Bsp matching APLx64 found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel IoT\Source-x64\BSP`

What would cause the error and how to I resolve that issue?
Thanks in advance.

I am using Windows 10 Pro 1809

The Target edition for the UWP app i have in mind is for 1809

The "Master Branch" version I have downloaded is currently 1809, version number 10.0.17763.x (downloaded from: https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/ )
[image]

Included bellow is a transcript of what was typed:

Transcript started, output file is

```
C:\Users\User\OneDrive\documents\PowerShell_transcript.YOB.MxCS9_JS.20190514184857.txt
IoTCorePShell arm 10.0.0.0 Test
PS C:\IoT-ADK-AddonKit\iot-adk-addonkit-master\iot-adk-addonkit-master\Workspace>New-IoTWorkspace C:\MyWorkspace3 App2 x64
New IoTWorkSpace available at C:\MyWorkspace3 for x64
Opening workspace : C:\MyWorkspace3\IoTWorkspace.xml
Corekit found OK
ADK_VERSION : 10.0.18362.1
IOTCORE_VER : 10.0.17763.253
BSP_VERSION : 10.0.0.0
ADDONKITVER : 6.0.190307.1402
HostOS Info : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro - 10.0.17763 - en-US
IOTWKSPACE  : C:\MyWorkspace3
OEM_NAME    : App2
BSP_ARCH    : amd64
BSPPKG_DIR  : C:\MyWorkspace3\Build\amd64\pkgs
MSPKG_DIR   : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\MSPackages\Retail\amd64\fre
Copying Registry.Version
Copying Custom.Cmd
Copying Provisioning.Auto
Copying OEM.Sample
Copying Device.SystemInformation
Copying DeviceLayout.GPT4GB
Copying DeviceLayout.GPT8GB-R
Copying DeviceLayout.MBR4GB
Copying DeviceLayout.MBR8GB-R
Workspace ready!
IoTCorePShell amd64 10.0.0.0 Test
PS C:\MyWorkspace3>Import-IoTOEMPackage *
Copying Appx.Certs
Copying Custom.BCD
Copying Custom.OOBEApp
Copying Custom.Settings
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Common\Packages\Device.SystemInformation already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Common\Packages\DeviceLayout.GPT4GB already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Common\Packages\DeviceLayout.GPT8GB-R already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Common\Packages\DeviceLayout.MBR4GB already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Common\Packages\DeviceLayout.MBR8GB-R already exist.
Copying Recovery.GPT-BCD
Copying Recovery.GPT-BcdEdit
Copying Recovery.MBR-BCD
Copying Recovery.MBR-BcdEdit
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Common\Packages\Registry.Version already exist.
Copying Security.BitLocker
Copying Security.DeviceGuard
Copying Security.DeviceGuardTest
Copying Security.SecureBoot
Copying Security.SecureBootTest
Copying Settings.HotKey
Copying Appx.IoTCoreDefaultApp
Copying Appx.IoTOnboardingTask
Copying AzureDM.Services
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Source-x64\Packages\OEM.Sample already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Common\ProdPackages\Custom.Cmd already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace3\Common\ProdPackages\Provisioning.Auto already exist.
Copying Recovery.WinPE
IoTCorePShell amd64 10.0.0.0 Test
PS C:\MyWorkspace3>Import-IoTBSP APLx64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel IoT\Source-x64\BSP"
Error: No Bsp matching APLx64 found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel IoT\Source-x64\BSP
```

Comment: What version of the Windows ADK do you have installed?  Do you have the WinPE addon for the Windows ADK installed?

Comment: I do have the Windows ADK and adjusted question regarding the building and the exact command.

Comment: If your trying to target 1803 then you need Windows ADK for 1803 installed instead of 1809.  Likewise, the WinPE addon, must be the same version.  Since only 1809 is supported you will have to go back to the separate [IoT Add-on](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/releases/tag/17134_v5.3) project and use that instead since the built-in one only supports 1809.

Comment: Well for some reason I cannot edit, in VS when my target it 1803 but that's by the by, i will change the target to 1809 when i get to that bridge right now i just want to get windows 10 IOT running on this hardware.

Comment: Your file structure doesn’t appear to match the directory you used in your command.

Comment: please let me know if theirs anything else i can add.

Answer (score 0):

was able to correctly run the command like follows:

```
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\user\OneDrive \documents\PowerShell_transcript.YOB.M75RE0yz.20190514193109.txt
IoTCorePShell arm 10.0.0.0 Test
PS C:\IoT-ADK-AddonKit\iot-adk-addonkit-master\iot-adk-addonkit-master\Workspace>New-IoTWorkspace C:\MyWorkspace5 App5 x64
New IoTWorkSpace available at C:\MyWorkspace5 for x64
Opening workspace : C:\MyWorkspace5\IoTWorkspace.xml
Corekit found OK
ADK_VERSION : 10.0.18362.1
IOTCORE_VER : 10.0.17763.253
BSP_VERSION : 10.0.0.0
ADDONKITVER : 6.0.190307.1402
HostOS Info : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro - 10.0.17763 - en-US
IOTWKSPACE  : C:\MyWorkspace5
OEM_NAME    : App5
BSP_ARCH    : amd64
BSPPKG_DIR  : C:\MyWorkspace5\Build\amd64\pkgs
MSPKG_DIR   : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\MSPackages\Retail\amd64\fre
Copying Registry.Version
Copying Custom.Cmd
Copying Provisioning.Auto
Copying OEM.Sample
Copying Device.SystemInformation
Copying DeviceLayout.GPT4GB
Copying DeviceLayout.GPT8GB-R
Copying DeviceLayout.MBR4GB
Copying DeviceLayout.MBR8GB-R
Workspace ready!
IoTCorePShell amd64 10.0.0.0 Test
PS C:\MyWorkspace5>Import-IoTOEMPackage *
Copying Appx.Certs
Copying Custom.BCD
Copying Custom.OOBEApp
Copying Custom.Settings
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Common\Packages\Device.SystemInformation already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Common\Packages\DeviceLayout.GPT4GB already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Common\Packages\DeviceLayout.GPT8GB-R already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Common\Packages\DeviceLayout.MBR4GB already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Common\Packages\DeviceLayout.MBR8GB-R already exist.
Copying Recovery.GPT-BCD
Copying Recovery.GPT-BcdEdit
Copying Recovery.MBR-BCD
Copying Recovery.MBR-BcdEdit
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Common\Packages\Registry.Version already exist.
Copying Security.BitLocker
Copying Security.DeviceGuard
Copying Security.DeviceGuardTest
Copying Security.SecureBoot
Copying Security.SecureBootTest
Copying Settings.HotKey
Copying Appx.IoTCoreDefaultApp
Copying Appx.IoTOnboardingTask
Copying AzureDM.Services
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Source-x64\Packages\OEM.Sample already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Common\ProdPackages\Custom.Cmd already exist.
Warning: C:\MyWorkspace5\Common\ProdPackages\Provisioning.Auto already exist.
Copying Recovery.WinPE
IoTCorePShell amd64 10.0.0.0 Test
PS C:\MyWorkspace5>Import-IoTBSP BSWx64 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel IoT\Source-x64\BSP\"
Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel IoT\Source-x64\BSP\\BSWx64
Warning:   Replacing Intel.BSW64.DeviceLayout with %OEM_NAME%.BSW64.DeviceLayout
Warning:   Replacing Intel.BSW64.GFX with %OEM_NAME%.BSW64.GFX
Warning:   Replacing Intel.BSW64.OEMDevicePlatform with %OEM_NAME%.BSW64.OEMDevicePlatform
BSP copy completed
```